# how to Auto push files to git repo using shell script

Tags: git, shell, jenkins

I am new to GIT..I have a requirement where we need to select few files from a dir and push those files to git repository using a shell script? Can any one help me out on how to achieve this? Can we automate this process using Jenkins?
That is, whenever we trigger jenkins job, that should select the required files based on some file format and push those to GIT repo?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is really simple to do. Jenkins can runs any script you choose in a job. Just write a script to handle the git stuff you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, here's a tiny bash example that will push files

```
#!/bin/bash

# add files you want to push here
# git add <stuff>

git push
```

---

Martin's comment seems to wholeheartedly say yes to the jenkins sidenote, but that might be better suited in another question, unless you find [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) useful

**sidenote:** a bash/git boilerplate i've found useful is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function pushIt () {
  # maybe some stuff before the push?
  # if so, add it here
  git push 
} 

# this is a convenient check for uncommitted changes, 
# a handy thing if the script's expected to grow
if [ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ];then
  pushIt
else
  echo "Repo isn't clean, commit or stash your changes"
fi
```